# How to replace wordpress registration url in a new page

Tags: php, wordpress

suppose, i have a new php file in wordpress named registration.php and this file placed on the root wordpress file.

i want to replace all the elements from 
http://siteurl/wp-login.php?action=register to

http://siteurl/registration.php

How to do it! Need Help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve this feature, you can simply use any of the available plugin for adding registration form on your page like https://wordpress.org/plugins/simplr-registration-form/

=> Then just create a page in Wordpress backend and name it as **registration**

=> Put the provided short-code on that page.

=> Get your registration page accessible as like http://www.siteurl/registration

hope it helps.

**@Note** I think as per WordPress point of view, accessing your registration page as you said like http://siteurl/registration.php is not a good practice

Comment: thanks it works i just need to edit one method inside of your suggested plug in :)

Comment: but Jenis sir when someone registered inside your given plug in mail verification to the admin is not occuring! they cant directly register ! how to apply mail verification on here or you have alternate plug in solution ?
Thanks!